# What is the benefits of a foreach-loop vs a body-less for-loop

Tags: c#, loops

In C# you can use a for-loop without declaring the body, what is the benefit of using this in production-code versus using a `foreach` loop?

## Example

My Examples below use reflection to get the property value of an object based on the `p_strPropertyPath` parameter. The method can also look at the property of a property, for example `MyClass.Property.SubProperty`.

In my opinion, the `foreach` loop is more obvious at what it is supposed to do, whereas the former looks cleaner to me.

### Body-less `For` Loop

The example below uses a body-less for-loop and an enumerator:

```
private string GetValue(MyClass p_objProperty, string p_strPropertyPath)
{
    string[] lstProperties = p_strPropertyPath.Split('.');
    IEnumerator objEnumerator = lstProperties.GetEnumerator();

    object objValue;

    for (
        objValue = p_objProperty;
        objValue != null && objEnumerator.MoveNext();
        objValue = objValue.GetType().GetProperty(objEnumerator.Current as string).GetValue(objValue)
        ) ;

    return Convert.ToString(objValue);
}
```

### `foreach` loop

The example below uses a `foreach` loop:

```
private string GetValue(MyClass  p_objProperty, string p_strPropertyPath)
{
    string[] lstProperties = p_strPropertyPath.Split('.');
    object objValue = p_objProperty;
    foreach (string strProperty in lstProperties)
    {
        objValue = objValue.GetType().GetProperty(strProperty).GetValue(objValue);
        if(objValue == null) break;
    }

    return Convert.ToString(objValue);
}
```

Comment: I don't think these two loops are doing the same thing (hence are not comparable).  In particular, the 2nd loop uses an uninitialized variable `objValue`.

Comment: Your first example is just a very clever `for` loop (a bit too clever).  `foreach` loops are meant to replace `for` loops in those instances where you don't require the loop variable as an index.  The `foreach` is especially useful here, where it replaces something that's rather unreadable with something that is quite readable.

Comment: Good points, my examples were bad as the first one I copied and pasted and the second one I hadn't checked if it worked correctly. I forgot to initialise `objValue` nor did I check if it was assigned as null.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thank you for the comment. That's why I asked the question -- I wanted to understand what others would think would be better in production code. I've seen the first example online a few times.

Comment: Where did you see the first example online?

Comment: I've seen something similar, though I wouldn't say exactly the same, as my example. But it was a while ago so I cannot for the life of me remember where.

Comment: What's with all the `p_xxx` variables? Please don't use Hungarian notation in C# code. Use meaningful variables names that clearly convey what the variable does. Even though he deleted the comment, I'm with @RobertHarvey and would want to have stern words with anyone on my team who wrote code like the first example. Always write code so that it is easy to read and thus obvious what it does.

Comment: You forgot to dispose the iterator in the first sample.

Comment: @DavidArno I copied it from code I was writing in production and unfortunately they use Hungarian notation here, which I find silly in C#, where VS will highlight the type, but useful in JavaScript. It also makes it harder to maintain the code if the type changes.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, I didn't realise it implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Code is not simply meant for the compiler, though the compiler is likely the only thing to understand your abominations. Code must be readable. By those poor guys who have to find bugs or have to implement changes. If you have bad luck, you might be that poor guy yourself just a few weeks from now.

Comment: Good heavens *please stop using Hungarian notation in C#*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested code is not equivalent if `lstProperties` is empty, (as ErikEidt points out, also if it is non-empty), if `p_objProperty` is null, or if `.GetValue()` returns null. All of those cases are quite relevant because the shown function is using reflection to traverse an object graph.

A for-loop without a body can be an elegant description when searching for a certain value, or when the loop body already happens as a side effect of the loop condition.

I don't think the shown code is a fantastic example of this feature, because both the loop condition *and* the iterator section have side effects. A classic for-loop is most applicable when all sections are fairly simple. It may be clearer to de-sugar the for-loop into a while loop, mostly because the code is a bit too complex for a single line:

```
object value = initialValue;
while (value != null && enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var propertyName = enumerator.Current as string;
    value = value.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(value);
}
```

If you were to use a foreach loop, take care to convert the exact loop condition, e.g. by breaking from the loop:

```
object value = initialValue;
foreach (string propertyName in properties)
{
    if (value == null) {
        break;
    }
    value = value.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(value);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I hadn't realised I missed the initialisation and null-checking. I updated my question. Do you think the foreach loop is better suited?

Comment: @BrownishMonster In the end, that is your call. In C#, I would probably prefer the foreach-loop. This would also be a very good fit for the Linq `Aggregate()` method which gets rid of the explicit loop: `object value = properties.Aggregate(initialValue, (v, property) => v?.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(v))`. In other languages, this problem also has an elegant recursive solution.

Comment: I would pull GetType() out of the loop as well. It is nearly surely returning the same value each time.

Comment: @FrankHileman That is rather unlikely to be correct, since most objects do not reference other instances of the same type exclusively. OP's `GetValue(x, "A.B.C")` method is supposed to be the reflection-based equivalent of the expression `x.A.B.C`, likely as part of a homegrown template engine.

Comment: I meant to pull it out of the loop, not turn it into a constant. The "value" variable has the same value in the loop, and it's type cannot change.

Comment: @FrankHileman No, the value changes with each loop iteration: `x, x.A, X.A.B` and so on may or may not be different objects with different types. Its runtime type may very well change, even though the static type of the variable is `object`. Or am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: No I misunderstood, forgetting it was mutated.